# reactjs navlink activeClassName not working on root

Tags: reactjs, react-navigation, nav, tailwind-css

I have using react `<Navlink>` for active route class like this with tailwind-css:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<NavLink to={'/'} activeClassName="text-orange-600 border-orange-600" className="block py-1 md:py-3 pl-1 align-middle text-gray-500 no-underline hover:text-gray-900 border-b-2 border-white hover:border-purple-500">
          Home
</NavLink>
```

But root (`/`) is showing always active while I clicked other links.

When go `/sale` page root `/` also showing activeclass

I want when go other pages and if `/sale` then only this links showing activeclasses not others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add the "exact" keyword for it to work only if "/"

https://reactrouter.com/web/api/NavLink

```
<NavLink exact to={'/'} activeClassName="text-orange-600 border-orange-600" className="block py-1 md:py-3 pl-1 align-middle text-gray-500 no-underline hover:text-gray-900 border-b-2 border-white hover:border-purple-500">
          Home
</NavLink>
```

Comment: it works properly so this is simple just add with this keyword